# How to define a method inside webservice static method

Tags: apex, integration

I am having a webserve static method and need to define a function which returns a string inside that webservice method

```
global class ABC 
{
   webservice static string XYZ()
  {
    // need to define that method inside XYZ method
  }
}
```

But while adding public string method inside webservice method . I am getting an error as  Unexpected token 'public'.Please let me know how can I add a method inside webservice method

Answer (score 1):

you can't declare method inside of the method. Do it on the same level, as webservice method.

```
global class ABC {
    webservice static string XYZ(){
        // calling EFG method
        EFG();
    }

    //private method on the same level as webservice
    private static void EFG(){
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Oleksandr . Just one doubt ,but what if that method has scope which is just needed within the webservice method .

Comment: You can pass what needed as params if the method EFG